# Is it safe to have two different databases for single project?

Tags: .net, database

I am developing a web application in .net. In the first page the user has to select whether it is a student or a staff who is logging in. As soon as the user selects, user will be redirected to the registration page.

Now I am in a confusion and see these three options:

- Do i have to create two different databases for storing staff details and student details?
- Is it fine to add all the details in single database?
- Is there any other way to implement it?

Which one of these options should I choose?

P.S.: A chat concept that connects students and staff members will be added later on.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow - I have edited your question to make it more focused and more readable. Please try and make sure in future questions that your focus is clear.

Comment: You did not post any reason that would suggest that using more than one database could be necessary. You can even store details of students and staff in one single table `person`.

Comment: A *database* is a *maintenance unit* rather than a design unit, as *databases* are individually backed up and restored. *Databases* of large applications routinely consist of hundreds or even thousands of tables. By splitting your application datastore between multiple *databases* you complicate the maintenance process, which should only be done for very cogent business reasons.

Comment: I pursued with a single database but suddenly I got confused that since I am creating a seperate login for staff and student I can have two different databases @VDohnal

Comment: @anusha: What vendor are we talking about? In SQL Server (for instance) using multiple schemas within a single database is often the most appropriate mechanism for security control on a role-based model. Other vendors have similar well established patterns

Comment: So thanks.!! I will include all details in a single database.!! But  I have seen many of the systems having multiple user login .Are they all storing in a single database? @PieterGeerkens

Comment: @anusha: Be careful in your terminology. In SQL Server a *login* is a *database server instance* object, while a *user* is an object contained within a single *database* object, which my or may not be mapped to a server *login*. Which object are you referring to?

Comment: I am actual referring to seperate registration  for staff and student @PieterGeerkens

Answer (score 0):

there is no problem of using two databases but in this case I'll suggest you to create two different table.one of them for students and one of them for staff,afterward you can create another table to save details of CHAT or something else...